# Linking a library located in different paths for various users

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio

Working on Windows with Visual Studio, I have a project lying in a git repository.
I need to link with this library to compile.
I'd like this project to build on different computers, on which the library can be located in different paths ( very huge library i cannot embed as a submodule or as a dependency )

How can i make it such that contributors to my repository can setup the project and select the location of the library, without actually modifying the project file ( .vcxproj ) which is tracked by git ?
Should i learn how to use CMAKE and not commit the Project file at all ?

Thank you ;)

Note:
I should add that the library is a static library .lib, and i considered using #pragma comment( lib, "yourLibrary.lib" ) but this would be comitted in the source aswell which is not good for my needs

Also, i'd like to setup this "custom" library path from visual studio GUI interface, and from command line aswell if i were to call "MSBUILD myproject.sln"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite an opinion based question, but I'll try to cover the two options you could consider.

First one is using an environment variable. When you specify the link library in VS, you use that variable. This covers the msbuild part, but doesn't do the VS GUI part, as you would need to restart VS.

CMake is indeed another solution. From its GUI, you can set up the path to the library, it generates the solution for the compiler you want (almost any VS version and 32/64bits + Linux).

You get the GUI to change the path in VS, but you loose the option to set the path on the command line to msbuild (you need to change it in CMake GUI or CmakeCache.txt).

The pragma version is a no-no option. This doesn't solve the PATH problem properly and is not portable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

I Guess i'll settle with CMake and not commit the project anymore: hopefully i can pass the path of the library to cmake when running it the first time after cloning the repository, that way the project will be generated with a configuration-dependant path, no matter if i then compile it from GUI or from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cmake for cross-platform projects but VS should be fine for Windows-only boxes. Modifying a library path across machines is a common use case and VS should handle it easily. The user-specific overrides of the default path should automatically be saved by VS to a separate file which would not need to be checked in. It's been a while since I've used VS, but that seems like how it would work :).